# Camera preview is letterboxed when on portrait

Tags: android, graphics, camera

I'm using the cameraPreview sample coming with the Android API demos. The problem is, the camera preview is showing properly on landscape, but when I rotate the phone to portrait, I get a letterboxed and rotated image.

I'm using Android 2.3.3 and a Samsung Galaxy Ace, but also tried 2.1 on a Xperia Mini 10 Pro.

A couple of pics (sorry for poor the quality):
[image: landscape]

[image: portrait]

Is this normal behavior of the demo program? What's a proper way to fix it?

Comment: Okay, now testing the APiDemos CameraPreview demo, it works perfectly. But when putting that code in a separate project, I get the problem shown above: when in straight portrait (Samsung logo upwards) I get a letterbox preview, then one landscape position is correct, one is upside-down. The other portrait position is not letterboxed, but also shown upside-down.

Comment: Bumping for desperation, please? :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Its a serious problem for me on Galaxy Tab 7. Camera preview takes up only upper right hand corner of screen (about 25% of screen)...

Comment: I did not. I had some rough weeks and moved on to another project. I might come back to this soon though.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem I was having that was very similar to this. It had to do with with an old <supports-screens ... /> entry I had in my manifest file. I removed this from my manifest and everything worked like a charm. Hopefully this might help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, turns out it was a problem with my manifest, I had to include a line defining a fixed screen orientation for the camera activity. :P

Comment: Doesn't work for me for portrait mode. My target is 2.1, testing on HTC Desire. Landscape works fine though. I tried changing the camera parameters but to no avail yet...

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me :

mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Comment: That solved the rotation on portrait but not the letterbox (and also screwed orientation on landscape, but I guess that won't be hard to solve). Are there any examples showing proper camera work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem I was having that was very similar to this. It had to do with with an old supports-screens ... / entry I had in my manifest file. I removed this from my manifest and everything worked like a charm. Hopefully this might help solve your problem. Cheers.

Comment: It's not my case, I have a plain, clean manifest file, almost empty. :(