# Show cropped image after video record android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

When I start to record video and stop a pause.Sometimes show me cropped image preview.How to avoid this behavior.I'm using intent for calling camera.Thanks.

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

My activity in manifest

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.mti.videodialy.activity.CreateVideoNoteActivity"
            android:theme="@style/VideoDailyActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of a device are you testing this on? 
May be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398089/camera-preview-is-letterboxed-when-on-portrait

Comment: I'm testing on nexus 5

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the same.Please help me

Comment: I gladly would if I had more information. Right now I can only point you in the right direction which is the keyword `letterboxing`

Comment: Maybe what you see is a side-effect of the file not being writable (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent ). If you click "V" at this stage, do you see a video file on storage?

Comment: Yes,I can save video and play it.I guess there just bitmap rotate when I finish record video.But how to fix it?